# WKWebView and XHR

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Currently working on a mobile app in Cordova and started development/testing on Android. Everything appears to work well and as expected on the Android platform. When switching to iOS we began running into problems. Decided to go with the WKWebView plugin and this seemed to help with some things, however, I am using a server to pull data via an API and I cannot anymore. Prior to using the WKWebView plugin the API was getting called and properly loading the information. I am using `access origin` in the `config.xml` to access this API. The main reason we can't go back to not using WKWebView is there was some weird rendering issues and scrolling wasn't "throw/toss" scrolling. You had to continuously swipe "up" or "down" to get it to move.

Was wondering if anyone here might have an idea on how to use WKWebView plugin, loading a local server to serve the `www` files from (mine is localhost:0), and also use `access origin` to access the API.

My config.xml

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test.testmobile" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        Mobile App for Android and iOS
    </description>
    <author email="test@test.com" href="test.com">
        test
    </author>
    <content src="http://localhost:0" />
    <access origin="http://10.1.0.215:6002" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="AlternateContentSrc" value="http://localhost:0" />
</widget>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using a server to pull data via an API and I cannot anymore.

Assuming this API is on an external server you're accessing with AJAX/XHR, the server response *must* contains CORS headers in order for WKWebView to accept it (see [this Cordova issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10144)).

> The main reason we can't go back to not using WKWebView is there was some weird rendering issues and scrolling wasn't "throw/toss" scrolling. You had to continuously swipe "up" or "down" to get it to move.

If WKWebView with Cordova becomes intolerable ([here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12037?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20wkwebview-known-issues) is a list of known issues), you may wish to consider [iScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) as a solution for native-feeling scrolling within UIWebView.